# Placement of constructor

Tags: vb.net, winforms

For Some reason in the following segment in my for each statment its declaring the  that the csv data cant be null even though as you see their when i create the csvData Object is its created within the loop is that the correct placement.

```
        For Each thisDocument As String In documentList

            filename = Path.GetFileName(thisDocument)
            SiteId = filename.Substring(0, filename.IndexOf("_"))

            Dim orderNumbers As String()
            Dim csvData As New DataTable
            Dim importUtils As New ImportController

            filename = Path.GetFileName(thisDocument)
            orderNumbers = filename.Split("_")
            location = filename.Substring(0, 3)
            importUtils = New ImportController(cfb.TargetFolder & filename)


            csvData = importUtils.ConvertCsvToDatatable(True)

            ImportDataTableToSql(cfb.TargetFolder & filename, csvData, cfb.StoreCompany)

        Next
```

edits to show convertcsvtodatatable()

```
Public Function ConvertCsvToDatatable(ByVal ColumnNames As Boolean) As DataTable
    Try
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        For Each columnName In GetColumnsfromCsv(ColumnNames, ",")
            dt.Columns.Add(columnName)
        Next
        Dim fileReader As New StreamReader(FileName)
        If ColumnNames Then
            fileReader.ReadLine()
        End If
        Dim line As String = fileReader.ReadLine
        While Not IsNothing(line)
            line = line.Replace(Chr(34), "")
            dt.Rows.Add(line.Split(","))
            line = fileReader.ReadLine
        End While
        fileReader.Close()
        Return dt
    Catch ex As Exception
        'log to file
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: importUtils.ConvertCsvToDatatable(true) could return null, and if it's the case, THAT is the method you should look into.

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Did you check if cfb.TargetFolder is a valid path?

Comment: Your initial `New DataTable` does not prevent you from a `NullReferenceException` if you assign `null`/`Nothing` later. So it's just misleading to initialize the `DataTable` if it gets actually created, filled and returned in the method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter please see above the weird thing is it works in another program just not how I have had it done here

Comment: @DavidB: an empty catch is bad practise, you're swallowing the exception and get `Nothing` as answer. There are multiple places where you can get an exception(f.e. in `GetColumnsfromCsv` which you haven't shown): Tell us the exception that is caught in your empty catch.

Comment: Apart from that you should handle the case that the table which is returned from `ConvertCsvToDatatable` can be `Nothing`: `If csvData IsNot Nothing Then ImportDataTableToSql(...)`